# Mapping WaterML data in cartodb

Tags: carto, api, usgs

Has anyone had success in mapping WaterML data in cartodb? ([WaterML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/waterml)). I can't get it to work and not sure what I am doing wrong. I also used this tool to generate a [REST URL](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/IV-Test-Tool.html) but still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WaterML is not a supported format by CartoDB. [Here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/datasets/#supported-file-formats)  you can find more information about the supported formats (GeoJson, Shapefile, CSV, KML,etc)